# Does using embedded content harm SEO/rankings

Tags: search, iframe, seo, search-engine

I am considering to put some flash games on a site I'm creating. These games have permission to be put on other sites by using iframes. Is there any possibility for my site to be penalised by search engines? Some other sites give permission to embed their games via embed/object tag. If using embed tag are penalties for duplicated content more likely? Many Flash games sites use content from other sources; infact one game could be found at 20-30 different sites with search engine indexation. What should I consider if I want good indexation of this iframe content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just having iframes on your site - will not harm you in any way, but also, embedded iframe content might NOT be indexed by some search engines.

Comment: I'm sorry, but no - 'the embedded content does not get indexed' is a myth.

You can test this out with this example form Codepen

`site:codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc Not a pure CSS solution - There are some pure CSS solutions`

Comment: cool. Anyway, time goes by, search engines improve :)